# iPhone Programming Random Views When I tap button

Tags: iphone

I have 5 different views and when I tap the button, I want to push one of 5 views randomly. However, I do not want to make 5 different controllers for each views. Do I have a chance to put them in one controller? If so, how?

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you mean with *"when i tap the button, i want to push one of 5 views randomly"*

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually, in my main view let's say there is button with name; "shops" and there are 5 different views. when i tap this button, new view must be chosen from 5 different views. Each time when i tap "shops" button, it should bring us different view. I apologize for my English :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have as many views as you want in a single UIViewController subclass.   You can create them all in Interface Builder as well, in the one .xib file for your UIViewController class (it might get a bit hard to see, though, better to lay out each UIView in its own .xib).  You can present them in any combination you want.   Assuming you want to just show one view at a time, you can do this:

In your viewDidLoad method, start out showing the initial view, and in your class keep track of which is the current view:

```
...
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *currentView;
...
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [self.view addSubview:self.defaultView];
    self.currentView = self.defaultView;
}

Then to switch to a particular other view do this:

- (void) switchToView:(UIView *)newView
{
    [self.currentView removeFromSuperView];
    [self.view addSubview:newView];
    self.currentView = newView;
}


}
```

Or you can show them all at one time: just [self.view addSubview:theView];

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now, i can make more than one views in single viewController.

Comment: Ahh sorry, actually i don't know the concept of this site. Is it okay now?

Comment: Thank you!    Accepting answers and keeping a high percentage of answers accepted will encourage others to spend time answering your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the view outlet of the controller on the action of the button. Use random numbers to select which view. Ouh and `- (void)setNeedsDisplay` :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the tags of all the views, and then use

```
int r = arc4random() % 5;
```

method to find the random number. Use this newly generated number to check the tag, in your selector